# Undefined variable: auth

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to get the value stored in `Auth::user()`

I created a new Controller with the name of `User_Controller` and in `index` method I am writing below code.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($auth->user());
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

It says

> Undefined variable: auth

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be `auth()` not `$auth`

`auth()` is a helper function for `Auth` class